# Limit of Euler's number failing due to precision errors - A surprising case. Why does it happen?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, floating-point, eulers-number-e, machine-precision

It is a known fact that floating point precision errors are bound to happen when one forces a computer to deal with very large or very small numbers, especially when both things are done at the same time. I was playing around with similar functions as the one described in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073522/why-special-limit-of-eulers-number-fails-at-higher-powers) question, that is functions of the type:
$$
g(f(x))=\left(1+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)^{f(x)} \\
$$
With $\lim_{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty$ and $f(x)$ a "rapidly" growing function of $x$, such as $e^{x}$, $\Gamma(x+1),x^{9}$ and so on. For each and everyone of these functions the plot I have behave similarly, as shows the first figure. I don't understand the zig-zag behavior very well, but the jump to 1 is easy to understand: $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ becomes so small that the computer treats it as $0$.

[image]

That all said, here comes the surprising stuff. It is known that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}=1$, and so $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}}}=1$. Hence $tan\left(\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{\Gamma(x+1)}}\right)$ should also go to infinity (in modulus, at least) with $x$. When I plot $g(f(x))$ with this tangent thing as $f$, numeric precision problems also disrupt the function, but they do so in a pretty strange way, as shows the second figure (I added a line for $1$ for comparison). There's no zig-zag (which doesn't trouble me that much actually), but only the function with a positive sign collapses into $1$, the negative collapses into $\approx 6.12961$.

[image: The case for the strange tangent functions]

Does anyone know why this particular function has such a strange behavior? Or at least what kind of material should I read to in order to discover the answer?

Is it possible to work out why it collapses into this particular number? Can we find other similar examples? Thank you!

Comment: All of your examples are based on peculiar behavior of floating point limitations which disappear when sufficient numerical precision is used.

Comment: That is true. But the fourth example is immensely different from the other ones. The behavior of the first three can be easily understood, but for the last one I have no explanation

Comment: If you really care about this, then I think you need to look into the code for the implementation of $\tan$ and $\Gamma$ on your system. It doesn't surprise me much that different initial conditions lead to behaviour that seems to converge to a common value but then jumps to one of two different equilibria.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237707/why-does-left1-frac1n-rightn-give-vastly-different-relative-errors and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238722/why-is-that-the-same-equation-with-different-x-values-produces-drastically-diffe for how the error oscillates between $\mu·f(x)$ and $1/(2f(x))$ for $f(x)>10^8$. That the situation becomes trivial for $f(x)>10^{16}$ was already explained in the linked thread.

Comment: In floating point precision, especially for the pi constant used, you get $N=\tan(\pi/2)=1.633123935319537·10^{+16}$. While this is large enough to truncate completely $1+\frac1N$ to $1$, it is still not too large to give a non-trivial result in $1-\frac1N$. The value of $(1-\frac1N)^{-N}$ then is, as observed, $6.129614098672075$